Spring Boot and Thymeleaf error, the data not appering when I add the data from the input
Image I'm submitting the pollThe application is used for creating polls, polls can have many questions and questions many options, So the issue is that when I add e new survey(poll) in default we have 4 fields the poll's name, first question and 2 options, i filled them up and then pressed the button add option and added 3 more options so it became 5 options for the first question, then i pressed the button add question and default we have 3 fields the question desc. and 2 options I filled them and then pressed button add option and here instead of adding an option to the second question it saves the second question with 2 options and creates the third question with question desc and 2 options null and 3rd option as it should in the second question.
The method is
@PostMapping("/poll/create")
public String createPoll(@ModelAttribute PollData pollData, Model model)
How it Is (WITH ERROR)
Question 1: Question 1
Option 1: option 1
Option 2: option 2
Option 3: option 3
Option 4: option 4
Option 5: option 5
Question 2: Second question
Option 1: option 2.1
Option 2: option 2.2
Question 3: null
Option 1: null
Option 2: null
Option 3: option 2.3
Option 4: option 2.4
Option 5: option 2.5

How should be
Question 1: Question 1
Option 1: option 1
Option 2: option 2
Option 3: option 3
Option 4: option 4
Option 5: option 5
Question 2: Second question
Option 1: option 2.1
Option 2: option 2.2
Option 3: option 2.3
Option 4: option 2.4
Option 5: option 2.5

package finki.ukim.mk.surveyKing.controller;

import finki.ukim.mk.surveyKing.model.*;
import finki.ukim.mk.surveyKing.service.OptionService;
import finki.ukim.mk.surveyKing.service.PollService;
import finki.ukim.mk.surveyKing.service.QuestionService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class PollController {
    @Autowired
    private PollService pollService;

    @Autowired
    private QuestionService questionService;

    @Autowired
    private OptionService optionService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("polls", pollService.getAllPols());
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/poll/{id}")
    public String viewPoll(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        Poll poll = pollService.getPollById(id);
        model.addAttribute("poll", poll);
        model.addAttribute("questions", poll.getQuestions());
        return "poll";
    }

    @GetMapping("/poll/create")
    public String createPollForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("poll", new Poll());
        return "create_poll";
    }

@PostMapping("/poll/create")
public String createPoll(@ModelAttribute PollData pollData, Model model) {
    // Log the pollData structure to check what is being submitted
    System.out.println("Poll Name: " + pollData.getName());
    for (int i = 0; i < pollData.getQuestions().size(); i++) {
        QuestionData questionData = pollData.getQuestions().get(i);
        System.out.println("Question " + (i + 1) + ": " + questionData.getText());
        for (int j = 0; j < questionData.getOptions().size(); j++) {
            OptionData optionData = questionData.getOptions().get(j);
            System.out.println("Option " + (j + 1) + ": " + optionData.getDescription());
        }
    }

    // Proceed with validation
    if (pollData.getName() == null || pollData.getName().isEmpty()) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Poll name is required");
        return "create_poll";
    }

    if (pollData.getQuestions() == null || pollData.getQuestions().isEmpty()) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "At least one question is required");
        return "create_poll";
    }

    for (QuestionData questionData : pollData.getQuestions()) {
        if (questionData.getText() == null || questionData.getText().isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "All questions must have text");
            return "create_poll";
        }

        if (questionData.getOptions() == null || questionData.getOptions().isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Each question must have at least one option");
            return "create_poll";
        }

        for (OptionData optionData : questionData.getOptions()) {
            if (optionData.getDescription() == null || optionData.getDescription().isEmpty()) {
                model.addAttribute("error", "All options must have descriptions");
                return "create_poll";
            }
        }
    }

    // If everything is fine, create the poll
    Poll poll = new Poll();
    poll.setName(pollData.getName());

    List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (QuestionData questionData : pollData.getQuestions()) {
        Question question = new Question();
        question.setText(questionData.getText());
        question.setPoll(poll);

        List<Option> optionList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (OptionData optionData : questionData.getOptions()) {
            Option option = new Option();
            option.setDescription(optionData.getDescription());
            option.setQuestion(question);
            option.setPoll(poll);
            optionList.add(option);
        }
        question.setOptions(optionList);
        questionList.add(question);
    }
    poll.setQuestions(questionList);

    pollService.createPoll(poll);

    return "redirect:/";
}



    @PostMapping("/vote")
    public String createVote(@RequestParam("selectedOptions") List<Integer> selectedOptionIds,
                             @RequestParam("pollId") int pollId) {

        for (Integer optionId : selectedOptionIds) {
            optionService.incrementVote(optionId);
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/poll/{id}/results")
    public String pollResults(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        Poll poll = pollService.getPollById(id);
        model.addAttribute("poll", poll);
        return "results";
    }
    @GetMapping("/poll/edit/{id}")
    public String editPollForm(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        Poll poll = pollService.getPollById(id);
        model.addAttribute("poll", poll);
        return "edit_poll"; // Create an "edit_poll.html" Thymeleaf template
    }

    @PostMapping("/poll/edit/{id}")
    public String editPoll(@PathVariable int id, @ModelAttribute PollData pollData) {
        Poll poll = pollService.getPollById(id);
        pollService.updatePoll(poll, pollData);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    @PostMapping("/poll/delete/{id}")
    public String deletePoll(@PathVariable int id) {
        pollService.deletePoll(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Create Poll</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div th:if="${error}" class="alert alert-danger">
    <p th:text="${error}"></p>
  </div>
  <h1 class="mt-4 mb-3">Create a New Poll</h1>
  <form th:action="@{/poll/create}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Poll Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div id="questionsContainer">
      <div class="form-group question-block">
        <label>Question:</label>
        <input type="text" name="questions[0].text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Question Text" required>

        <div class="optionsContainer">
          <div class="form-group option-block">
            <input type="text" name="questions[0].options[0].description" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Option 1" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group option-block">
            <input type="text" name="questions[0].options[1].description" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Option 2" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary add-option-btn mb-2">Add Option</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" id="addQuestionBtn">Add Question</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-2">Create Poll</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  let questionIndex = 1; // Tracks the current number of questions
  let optionIndices = { 0: 2 }; // Tracks the current number of options for each question

  // Function to add a new question block
  function addQuestionBlock() {
    const questionsContainer = document.getElementById('questionsContainer');

    const newQuestionBlock = document.createElement('div');
    newQuestionBlock.className = 'question-block form-group';
    newQuestionBlock.setAttribute('data-question-index', questionIndex); // Set data attribute for easier access
    newQuestionBlock.innerHTML = `
        <label>Question:</label>
        <input type="text" name="questions[${questionIndex}].text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Question Text" required>

        <div class="optionsContainer">
            <div class="form-group option-block">
                <input type="text" name="questions[${questionIndex}].options[0].description" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Option 1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group option-block">
                <input type="text" name="questions[${questionIndex}].options[1].description" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Option 2" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary add-option-btn mb-2">Add Option</button>
    `;

    questionsContainer.appendChild(newQuestionBlock);

    // Initialize the option index for this question
    optionIndices[questionIndex] = 2;

    // Add event listener for adding options in this question block
    newQuestionBlock.querySelector('.add-option-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
      addOption(newQuestionBlock.querySelector('.optionsContainer'), questionIndex);
    });

    questionIndex++; // Increment the question index
  }

  // Function to add a new option within a specific question block
  function addOption(optionsContainer, questionIdx) {
    // Ensure the option index for this question is initialized
    if (typeof optionIndices[questionIdx] === 'undefined') {
      optionIndices[questionIdx] = optionsContainer.querySelectorAll('.option-block').length;
    }

    const optionCount = optionIndices[questionIdx];

    // Create a new input for the option without replacing the entire innerHTML
    const newOptionInput = document.createElement('div');
    newOptionInput.className = 'form-group option-block';
    newOptionInput.innerHTML = `
        <input type="text" name="questions[${questionIdx}].options[${optionCount}].description" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Option ${optionCount + 1}" required>
    `;

    optionsContainer.appendChild(newOptionInput);

    // Increment the option index for this question
    optionIndices[questionIdx]++;
  }

  // Add event listener for the initial add-question button
  document.getElementById('addQuestionBtn').addEventListener('click', addQuestionBlock);

  // Add event listener for the initial add-option button in the first question
  document.querySelector('.add-option-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const firstOptionsContainer = document.querySelector('.optionsContainer');
    addOption(firstOptionsContainer, 0); // 0 is the index of the first question
  });

  // Ensure form submission only happens when all data is correctly in place
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    let isValid = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < questionIndex; i++) {
      const questionText = document.querySelector(`input[name="questions[${i}].text"]`);
      if (!questionText || questionText.value.trim() === '') {
        alert(`Question ${i + 1} must have text.`);
        isValid = false;
        break;
      }

      const optionsCount = optionIndices[i];
      if (optionsCount === undefined || optionsCount < 1) {
        alert(`Question ${i + 1} must have at least one option.`);
        isValid = false;
        break;
      }

      for (let j = 0; j < optionsCount; j++) {
        const optionText = document.querySelector(`input[name="questions[${i}].options[${j}].description"]`);
        if (!optionText || optionText.value.trim() === '') {
          alert(`Option ${j + 1} in Question ${i + 1} must have text.`);
          isValid = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (!isValid) break;
    }

    if (!isValid) {
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      console.log("Form is valid, submitting...");
    }
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>



the explanation is extremely confusing, please rewrite it and delete everything irrelevant downsizing it to WHEN I press foo THEN happens bar BUT expected baz. Also the code is way too complicated, and there is too much of it, we don't have static compilers in our heads and won't be able to help you until you reduce it to the few relevant code blocks that cause the issue. Use debugger to understand where the problem happens and then only post that relevant part.

I can not delete the code, this is essential for this problem, I explained a little bit more about the problem I hope that was clear, if somebody has any questions please do not hesitate to ask, I will try my best to answer it
